# How can I count Symbols a better way and integrate all possible Symbols in my RegEx (except a-zA-Z0-9ßäÄöÖüÜ)?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strlen

First i Googled and search in Stackoverflow, but nothing fits my issue, so i create a question:

I use TYPO3 8.7.7, but don't think that this is important for that issue.

I want to count the Symbols in a Password-String, for checking it against a Number-Value, that i dynamically get from the Annotation of that function.

My Testpassword is `` abcDEF123456^°!"§$%&/()=?`ßöäüÖÄÜ€@;,:.-_#'+*/\-+*/= ``

First i remove all alphanumeric chars, including german special character.

```
// Remove all Non-Symbols
$symbolsOnly = preg_replace('/([[:alpha:][:digit:]äÄöÖüÜß])/', '', $password);
// Count Symbols
$symbolCount = strlen($symbolsOnly);
```

The Debug of `$symbolsOnly`:

> $symbolsOnly
>
> '^°!"§$%&/()=?`€@;,:.-_#'+*/-+*/=' (37 chars)

I have only 33 real chars here, but the Debug counts 37 chars.

So I start a JSON-Debug:

> json_encode($symbolsOnly)
>
> '"^\u00b0!\"\u00a7$%&/()=?`\u20ac@;,:.-_#'+*/\-+*/="' (55 chars)

### Just calculating

If I remove `\u00b0` (6 chars), `\u00a7` (6 chars) and `\u20ac` (6 chars), **i got 18 chars**.

If I remove the Escaping `\` from `"` (1 char), from `/` (3 char), from `\` (1 char) **I got 5 chars**.

If I remove the leading `"` and ending `"` **I got 2 chars**.

55 - 18 - 5 - 2 = 30 chars.

Now If add 3 chars (the full "converted" and not only escaped chars from the first line of "this calculation" I got my 33 chars.

So the json_encode works fine.

---

I googled a bit more and stackoverflowed too, so I get some informations for replacing the 3 "bad symbols".

```
/**
 * Replace: ° (json: \u00b0 hex: \xB0     ),
 *          § (json: \u00a7 hex: \xA7     ),
 *          € (json: \u20ac hex: \x{20AC} )
 * With:    ^ (a countable character)
 */
$symbolsOnly = preg_replace('/(\xB0|\xA7|\x{20AC})/u', '^', $symbolsOnly);
```

Now my debug looks correct:

> $symbolCount
>
> 33 (integer)

### But did I forgot some Characters, that could match more than one Character, if i count it with strlen()?

Comment: does `mb_strlen()` return the right count?

Comment: Thanks, yes that is the better way, I was searching for. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) to count multi-byte characters:

```
$password = 'abcDEF123456^°!"§$%&/()=?`ßöäüÖÄÜ€@;,:.-_#\'+*/\-+*/=';
$symbolsOnly = preg_replace('/([[:alpha:][:digit:]äÄöÖüÜß])/', '', $password);
$symbolCount = mb_strlen($symbolsOnly);
echo $symbolCount ; // 33
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I accept your answer as soon as I can.